# I can't get anything to install when running User Data for my EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, yum

If I am SShed into my AWS EC2 instance then I can run the command:
`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk` to install the Java JDK no problem. When I try to run my shell script in User-Data for the instance, nothing happens. No errors, and it says the User-Data was successfully modified but when I run `java -version`, then I am told that `java` is not a command.

Commands that don't need installation, like creating a folder work fine.

This is how I am running my shell script in the User-Data:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk;
--//
```

Comment: I have two points to add here, not sure if you already know these:

`01. You don't need sudo in user-data, it runs as root user by default.`
`02. User data does not run every time, it runs only first time when you create the instance. After than it won't run even if you change user-data.`

Comment: BTW, you could simply pass those last two lines (#! and yum) in the script rather than using mime.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  ahh good to know. Examples I saw all used mime. Do you know why I would ever need to use mime?

Comment: Maybe if you need to pass multiple things to the instance? Here's some examples of the simpler method: [Running commands on your Linux instance at launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing`-y` flag which confirms any prompts
`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y`

Comment: The `-y` flag automatically confirms any prompts. Also, remove `sudo` from User Data scripts (as per @Chandan).